# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1

Tags: python, json, api, decode

I am new to Python and I am having trouble tracing exactly what is triggering this error, seeing as I am not at all proficient at reading these errors yet. But from what I read, it could either be an issue with the API, or decoding the JSON. But I could really use some help with this.

Here is the exact error (I feel it is more useful to show this first, considering it references a few different parts of the code when declaring the error):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
    import sendgrid
  File "C:\Users\ikrom\Documents\authhgg\sendgrid.py", line 221, in <module>
    print(sg.login())
  File "C:\Users\ikrom\Documents\authhgg\sendgrid.py", line 50, in login
    return {"status_code": login.status_code, "response":login.json()}
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 898, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Python38\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Here are the code snippets of my code it references, I beleive...

line 7 in main is purely just me importing the module sendgrid.py from the root project folder. So all the code isnt in one file...the following are the snippets from sendgrid.py causing the other errors coming directly from my files.

```
login_page = f"https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/blocks.get.json?api_user={self.email}&api_key={self.password}&date=1"
        login_headers = {
            "Authorization": "token undefined",
            "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
            "Origin": "https://app.sendgrid.com",
            "Connection": "keep-alive" 
        }
        login = requests.get(login_page,
                              headers=login_headers,
                              proxies=self.proxy)
        print(login.text)
        return {"status_code": login.status_code, "response":login.json()}
```

line 50 is the last line, i also included all the lines leading up to it contained within the function:

And all the other line of my code the error references (line 221 of sendgrid.py) is running the function the above code is defining.

If you have any ideas why I am getting this please let me know.

Comment: Seems like the API has sent back invalid JSON, which is causing `login.json()` to throw an exception. What I suspect might be happening is that perhaps the login failed, so the server returned an empty response. And if you try to use the `json` module to decode an empty string, you will get that exact error. You should probably check the status code first and make sure that's valid before decoding the JSON.

Comment: What is the value of `login.content`?

Comment: sg.login()?? 

login_page = f"https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/blocks.get.json?api_user={self.email}&api_key={self.password}&date=1"
        login_headers = {
            "Authorization": "token undefined",
            "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
            "Origin": "https://app.sendgrid.com",
            "Connection": "keep-alive" 
        }
        login = requests.get(login_page,
                              headers=login_headers,
                              proxies=self.proxy)
        print(login.text)...the rest, its posted above but had to cut short for length